# How do i dump data from an Oracle Database without access to the database's file system

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to dump the schema and data from an existing Oracle DB and import it into another Oracle DB.

I have tried using the "Export Wizard" provided by sqldeveloper.

I found answers using Oracle Data Pump, however i do not have access to the filesystem of the DB server.

I expect to get a file that i can copy and import into another DB

Comment: What issue did you have with the export wizard? And can the two databases communicate directly (via a DB link)? Or can the database see the same filesystem, even if you can't?

Comment: I access the DB from a remote VM, which i cannot link to my machine. The VM is in a secured network which can access the DB, and i can transfer files from the VM to me. I can't connect to the DB server machine's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Without Data Pump, you have to make some concessions.

The biggest concession is you're going to ask a Client application, running somewhere on your network, to deal with a potentially HUGE amount of data/IO.

Withing reasonable limits, you can use the Tools > Database Export wizard to build a series of SQLPlus style scripts, both DDL (CREATEs) and DATA (INSERTs).

Once you have those scripts, you can use SQLPlus, SQLcl, or SQL Developer to run them on your new/target database.

Comment: I used the Database Export wizard, and asked for the data (in addition to the schema), as INSERT statements, but i only got the schema. I suspect it's a permissions issue, but it's weird since i have the permissions to SELECT the data

Comment: Getting the ddl is harder than the data actually privilege wise...version of SQLDev? Logs?